# Why do we have Indirect bandgap semiconductor?

Tags: material-science, semiconductor-physics

If the energy of an electron is proportional to square of the momentum **k**, how come we have a Indirect Bandgap material in which the minimum of the energy in conduction band is not at **k** not zero.

**P.S.**    :I know there is already a well discussed question on why there is a direct bandgap material, but i didn't get the answer. So please bear with me again.

Comment: Which other Phys.SE question?

Answer (score 2):

In the free-electron approximation, the electron energy is indeed $\frac{(\hbar k)^2}{2m}$ with a minimum at $k=0$. However, in a real material the electron is not free, and feels a background potential due to the distribution of the other charges, which modifies the $E(k)$ relationship. In a material with low symmetry, I presume this can also shift the minimum away from $k=0$.

Comment: Not just low symmetry - Silicon has an indirect gap, while the III-V materials have direct gaps.  For Si there is local minimum at k=0, it just isn't the global minimum.